# I can't view my laptop on TV

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I have a Compaq c770 with an Intel graphic chipset. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I plug the TV through a S-VIDEO port. However, nothing appears on the TV.

Ubuntu detects the TV, and I can configure it.  However, the TV is still black.

When I write `xrandr --verbose` it shows this:

---

TV1 connected 1024x768+1280+0 (0x4b) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm

Identifier: 0x43

Timestamp:  1262326

Subpixel:   unknown

```
Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0

Brightness: 1.0

Clones:    

CRTC:       1

CRTCs:      1 0

Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000

            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000

            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

           filter: 

bottom margin: 37 (0x00000025)  range:  (0,100)

right margin: 46 (0x0000002e)   range:  (0,100)

top margin: 36 (0x00000024) range:  (0,100)

left margin: 54 (0x00000036)    range:  (0,100)

mode:   NTSC-M

    supported: NTSC-M       NTSC-443     NTSC-J       PAL-M       

               PAL-N        PAL          480p@59.94Hz 480p@60Hz   

               576p         720p@60Hz    720p@59.94Hz 720p@50Hz   

               1080i@50Hz   1080i@60Hz   1080i@59.94H
```

848x480 (0x49)   29.0MHz +preferred

```
    h: width   848 start  849 end  912 total  944 skew    0 clock   30.7KHz

    v: height  480 start  481 end  512 total  513           clock   59.9Hz
```

640x480 (0x4a)   22.6MHz +preferred

```
    h: width   640 start  641 end  704 total  736 skew    0 clock   30.7KHz

    v: height  480 start  481 end  512 total  513           clock   59.9Hz
```

1024x768 (0x4b)   53.8MHz *current

```
    h: width  1024 start 1025 end 1088 total 1120 skew    0 clock   48.0KHz

    v: height  768 start  769 end  800 total  801           clock   59.9Hz
```

800x600 (0x4c)   34.0MHz

```
    h: width   800 start  801 end  864 total  896 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz

    v: height  600 start  601 end  632 total  633           clock   59.9Hz
```

---

I really don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Are you booting up with the tv plugged in, or are you plugging it in after ubuntu is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

If the TV has more than one VGA ports make sure you select the TV output to the right one (like VGA1 or VGA2). That has to be done with the TV remote controller.

If that does not help, what graphic card do you have?

Comment: I'm using the right output in the TV because when I boot up Windows it's works. I have a Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator X3100 graphic card.

Comment: Could be a problem with the graphic card?

Answer (score 0):

Many times with these laptops you have to press a key combination to switch the display to either be on both monitors, or either one or the other. I don't think they usually support "stretching" the desktop across both monitors. Usually one of the F-keys will have a picture of a monitor on it, press the Fn (Function) key and that to toggle the three modes.

Comment: I'm booting up with the plugged.

Comment: I'm booting up with the plugged. I'm plugging trough a s-video 8 pin --> scart cable. I'm not using the vga port, sorry for that mistake. Pressing the Fn keys doesn't work. I have a Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator X3100 graphic card. My TV only accepts PAL mode. When I change it with xrandr, the TV is still in black